# Type 2 slowly changing dimensions conversion (Teradata 14.10)

Tags: sql, relational-database, teradata

I have a table like

```
KeyField DeltaField SomeField Row_Ins_Ts
1        a          1         '2016-01-01 00:00:00'
1        a          2         '2016-01-02 00:00:00'
1        b          3         '2016-01-03 00:00:00'         
1        a          4         '2016-01-04 00:00:00'
2        d          5         '2016-01-01 00:00:00'
2        d          6         '2016-01-02 00:00:00'
2        e          7         '2016-01-03 00:00:00'
2        e          8         '2016-01-04 00:00:00'
```

I need to get the intervals where each value of DeltaField was current for a given KeyField.

The result set for the above data set would be:

```
KeyField DeltaField Rec_Strt_Ts            Rec_End_Ts
1        a          '2016-01-01 00:00:00'  '2016-01-02 23:59:59'
1        b          '2016-01-03 00:00:00'  '2016-01-03 23:59:59'      
1        a          '2016-01-04 00:00:00'  '9999-12-31 23:59:59' 
2        d          '2016-01-01 00:00:00'  '2016-01-02 23:59:59'
2        e          '2016-01-03 00:00:00'  '9999-12-31 23:59:59'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm trying this with Vertica instead of Teradata, but both fortunately support the ANSI 99 standard: Window functions, also called OLAP or analytic functions, and the WITH clause with several global table expressions depending from each other.

The first global table expression is just to generate your example data; the second belongs to the query, as you can't usually put an OLAP function into a WHERE clause and therefore need to get it in a subselect. And the LAG() OLAP function is what you need in order to be able to filter out the rows that have the same `deltafield` as their predecessor. So, in the final query, I can filter for `deltafield <> prev_deltafield` and use the LEAD() OLAP function and subtract one second from it to get the end timestamp. And I use the IFNULL() function to cater for the situation where I don't have a LEAD() or a LAG() value. Synonyms for IFNULL() can be NVL() or VALUE(). COALESCE() would work too, but it's slower because it has a variable number of arguments. See here:

```
WITH foo(keyfield,deltafield,somefield,row_ins_ts) AS (
          SELECT 1,'a',1, TIMESTAMP '2016-01-01 00:00:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,'a',2, TIMESTAMP '2016-01-02 00:00:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,'b',3, TIMESTAMP '2016-01-03 00:00:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,'a',4, TIMESTAMP '2016-01-04 00:00:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'d',5, TIMESTAMP '2016-01-01 00:00:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'d',6, TIMESTAMP '2016-01-02 00:00:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'e',7, TIMESTAMP '2016-01-03 00:00:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'e',8, TIMESTAMP '2016-01-04 00:00:00'
)
,    add_previous_deltafield AS (
SELECT
  keyfield
, deltafield
, LAG(deltafield) OVER(PARTITION BY keyfield ORDER BY row_ins_ts) AS prev_deltafield
, row_ins_ts
FROM foo
)
SELECT
  keyfield
, deltafield
, row_ins_ts AS rec_start_ts
, IFNULL(
    LEAD(row_ins_ts) OVER(
      PARTITION BY keyfield ORDER BY row_ins_ts
    ) - INTERVAL '1 SECOND'
  , '9999-12-31 23:59:59'
  ) AS rec_end_ts
FROM add_previous_deltafield
WHERE deltafield <> IFNULL(prev_deltafield,'')
ORDER BY keyfield;
```

Happy Playing - 
Marco the Sane

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to Window functions (which are nice because they are portable), you can use Teradata's built in Period logic as well as some built in functions to quickly tackle this.

Basically this will take three parts:

1. Convert your timestamp to a Period(Timestamp). Period types in Teradata have a start and an end point and take the form `Period(<begindate>, <enddate>)` and work with date or timestamps.
2. Using built in function TD_NORMALIZE_OVERLAP_MEET we can squeeze together multiple records of overlapping or meeting periods based on a field or fields.
3. We then take the beginning of the period that results from that function.

In your example:

```
WITH subtbl(keyfield, deltafield, durations) AS
(
    SELECT
        keyfield,
        deltafield,
        PERIOD(row_ins_ts, row_ins_ts + INTERVAL '1' DAY )  AS durations
    FROM
        <yourtable>
) 
SELECT keyfield, deltafield, BEGIN(durations) 
FROM TABLE
    (
        TD_NORMALIZE_OVERLAP_MEET (NEW VARIANT_TYPE(subtbl.keyfield, subtbl.deltafield), subtbl.durations)
        RETURNS (keyfield INTEGER, deltafield CHAR(1), durations PERIOD(TIMESTAMP(0)), numRecords INTEGER) 
        HASH BY keyfield, deltafield
        LOCAL ORDER BY keyfield, deltafield, durations
    ) AS dt(keyfield, deltafield, durations, numRecords)    
ORDER BY 1, 2;
```

Which outputs:

```
+----------+------------+------------------+
| keyfield | deltafield | BEGIN(durations) |
+----------+------------+------------------+
|        1 | a          | 1/4/2016 0:00    |
|        1 | a          | 1/1/2016 0:00    |
|        1 | b          | 1/3/2016 0:00    |
|        2 | d          | 1/1/2016 0:00    |
|        2 | e          | 1/3/2016 0:00    |
+----------+------------+------------------+
```